# Using Omnipay gateway in Sylius with Payum + OmnipayBridge

Tags: php, sylius, omnipay, payum

I have implemented an Omnipay gateway that I now would like to use in Sylius which uses [`payum`](https://github.com/Payum/Payum) 1.3, `payum-bundle` 1.0, and `omnipay-bridge` 1.0.

I have configured the gateway (it's a redirecting one that shows a separate payment page and, once payment is completed, will call the `returnUrl`, and no credit cards involved) in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
payum:
    gateways:
        my_gateway:
            omnipay_offsite:
                type: MyOmnipayGateway
                options:
                    gatewayOption: 1
                    anotherOption: 2
              actions:
                  - sylius.payum.my_gateway.action.convert_payment
```

and I have added the gateway to `sylius_payment` section as well

```
sylius_payment:
    gateways:
        my_gateway: My Payment Service
```

I have added an action to convert the payment to `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/PayumBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`:

```
<service id="sylius.payum.my_gateway.action.convert_payment" class="Sylius\Bundle\PayumBundle\Action\ConvertPaymentToMyGatewayAction">
    <tag name="payum.action" context="my_gateway" />
</service>
```

and implemented the `ConvertPaymentToMyGatewayAction` class that now converts the request payload to expected format (used `ConvertPaymentToPaypalExpressAction` as reference).

I have also added `MyOmnipayGateway` to the list of gateways in `vendor/omnipay/common/composer.json` to get past error that says the gateway is not supported.

Now when I complete the order I am succesfully redirected to my actual payment site, and once payment is completed returned to the provided `returnUrl` with expected parameters in query string. However here the execution goes back to `OffsiteCaptureAction` and calls `purchase` with same parameters as the call was originally made and I get redirected to the payment site again and again.

Current questions:

1. How to avoid adding configuration options under `vendor` folder - namely the mentioned `services.xml` and Omnipay's `composer.json`?
2. Where to handle the payment response? I need to check the `returnUrl` query string parameters (implemented in my gateway's `completePurchase`).

Thanks!

**Edit:** I missed initializing `$details` in my convert action with `$details = $payment->getDetails();` which caused the `_completeCaptureRequired` be false every time and thus `purchase` was executed in a loop. I can now handle the payment properly, ie. question 2 is pretty much solved with the config above and this handler

```
<?php
namespace Sylius\Bundle\PayumBundle\Action;

use Payum\Core\Action\ActionInterface;
use Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException;
use Payum\Core\Request\Convert;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\PaymentInterface;

class ConvertPaymentToMyGatewayAction implements ActionInterface
{
    public function execute($request)
    {
        RequestNotSupportedException::assertSupports($this, $request);

        /** @var PaymentInterface $payment */
        $payment = $request->getSource();
        $order = $payment->getOrder();

        $details = $payment->getDetails();

        // Fill the correct parameters here

        $request->setResult($details);
    }

    public function supports($request)
    {
        return
            $request instanceof Convert &&
            $request->getSource() instanceof PaymentInterface &&
            $request->getTo() === 'array'
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: follow this link that talk about Payum integration
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5715

Comment: Thanks for the handy reference, i've been wanting to add an extra payment gateway to my site for a while now. This will help. Any chance you can upload all of the code to a git repo or a sylius branch?

Comment: @Brett That's pretty much all the code (apparently refund does not call Payum) since we first wrote an Omnipay gateway. But anyways the code is here https://github.com/vesse/SyliusPayumCheckoutFiBundle

Answer (score 0):

To answer Question 1. You can add your own service to your app config or your own bundle. I like to put it in my own bundle, then when updating sylius it won't get touched.

```
<service id="sylius.payum.my_gateway.action.convert_payment" class="Sylius\Bundle\PayumBundle\Action\ConvertPaymentToMyGatewayAction">
    <tag name="payum.action" context="my_gateway" />
</service>
```

Just convert that to yml

```
sylius.payum.my_gateway.action.convert_payment:
    class: Sylius\Bundle\PayumBundle\Action\ConvertPaymentToMyGatewayAction
    tags:
        -  { name: payum.action, context: my_gateway }
```